# Typescript error in Vue 3 on input checkbox with v-bind

Tags: typescript, vue.js

The following checkbox

```
<input
v-model="filter.closed"
true-value="-1"
false-value="0"
type="checkbox"
@change="UpdateFilter()"
/>
```

creates the typescript error:
"Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'any[] | Booleanish | undefined'.ts(2322)"

"filter.closed" is a number indeed. I store all booleans as numbers in my MySQL database.
And I told vue to handle -1 as true and 0 as false, but TS (or the linter or whatever is in charge) doesn't seem to recognize this.

I run VSCode with the Volar extension.

I this a bug or can I teach the transpiler somehow to treat -1 as true?

Comment: `!!filter.closed`?

Comment: There is a filter object with a numeric property named "closed".
It looks like this:
filter: {
 closed: 0,
 id: "",
 etc...
}